# How to get usage statistics from Databricks or SQL Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, statistics, databricks

I am looking for a way to get usage statistics from Databricks (Data Science & Engineering and SQL persona).

For example:

- I created a table. I want to know how many times a specific user queried that table.
- How many times a pipeline was triggered?
- How long it took to run a DLT pipeline?

Is there any way to get usage statistics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to get usage statistics from Databricks:

**Databricks UI:**
The Databricks UI provides information on the usage of tables, notebooks, and jobs. You can view the number of times a table was accessed, the number of times a notebook was run, and the duration of a job run.

**Audit Logs:**
Databricks maintains audit logs that can be used to track user activity and monitor usage statistics. These logs contain information on the type of activity performed, the user who performed the activity, and the time the activity was performed.

**Databricks REST API:**
The Databricks REST API provides programmatic access to Databricks resources, including usage statistics. You can use the API to retrieve information on table usage, job run history, and other usage statistics.

**Databricks Delta Metrics:**
Databricks Delta provides detailed metrics on the usage of Databricks Delta tables, including information on the number of reads and writes, the size of the tables, and the duration of job runs.

freel free to refer this doc : https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to send the statistics to Power BI. Which method is the best choice for this purpose? And about Rest API, do you know any sample code/documentation to get usage statistics by Rest API?

Comment: Unfortunately not, please describe the complete question or create a separate question for that. I have answered only what you asked. Please mark it as "Solved"